# XSLT solution to repetative pattern

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT 1 (can't use 2 for reasons out of scope)

I am encountering the same repetitive output generation from tags. My XML document has literally hundreds of different tags but all share a common trait: They have an attribute named uom. When I generate output, I always want to concatenate the attribute to the element's value e.g.

```
<a uom="km">10</a>
<b uom="m">5</a>
<c uom="l">2</c>
```

should output to

```
10 km
5 m
2 l
```

The a, b, c of course in my example is largely simplified and the actual tags are grim long words from ISO schemas. Is there a way to prevent the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="a"><xsl:value-of select="a/@uom">
<xsl:value-of select="b"><xsl:value-of select="b/@uom">
<xsl:value-of select="c"><xsl:value-of select="c/@uom">
```

by doing something to the tune of the next pseudo-xslt:

```
<xsl:procedure name="douom">
<xsl:value-of select="."><xsl:value-of select="@uom">
</xsl:procedure>
```

and then

```
<xsl:call-procedure name="douom" param="a"/>
<xsl:call-procedure name="douom" param="b"/>
<xsl:call-procedure name="douom" param="c"/>
```

The only way I know to do this with a template is by having

```
match="a|b|c"
```

but in reality the match string for me will be miles long if i need to register each element separated by |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
<xsl:template match="*[@uom]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', @uom)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

whether you also need `<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@uom]"/>` depends on which other elements or nodes you want to process.